# How to check if a pipe is empty and run a command on the data if it isn't?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I have piped a line in bash script and want to check if the pipe has data, before feeding it to a program.

Searching I found about `test -t 0` but it doesn't work here. Always returns false.
So how to be sure that the pipe has data?

Example:

```
echo "string" | [ -t 0 ] && echo "empty" || echo "fill"
```

Output: `fill`

```
echo "string" | tail -n+2 | [ -t 0 ] && echo "empty" || echo "fill"
```

Output: `fill`

Unlike [Standard/canonical way to test whether foregoing pipeline produced output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276199/standard-canonical-way-to-test-whether-foregoing-pipeline-produced-output) the input needs to be preserved to pass it to the program. This generalizes [How to pipe output from one process to another but only execute if the first has output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13326/how-to-pipe-output-from-one-process-to-another-but-only-execute-if-the-first-has) which focuses on sending email.

Comment: Very similar: [Make a pipe conditional on non-empty return](//superuser.com/q/210054/354511) (on [SU])

Comment: A pipe in not a terminal.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There's no way to peek at the content of a pipe using commonly available shell utilities, nor is there a portable way to read a character from the pipe then put it back. The only way to know that a pipe has data is to read a byte, and then you have to get that byte to its destination.

So do just that: read one byte; if you detect an end of file, then do what you want to do when the input is empty; if you do read a byte then fork what you want to do when the input is not empty, pipe that byte into it, and pipe the rest of the data.

```
first_byte=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null | od -t o1 -A n | tr -dc 0-7)
if [ -z "$first_byte" ]; then
  # stuff to do if the input is empty
else
  {
    printf "\\$first_byte"
    cat
  } | {
    # stuff to do if the input is not empty
  }      
fi
```

The [`ifne`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ifne) utility from [Joey Hess's moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) runs a command if its input is not empty. It usually isn't installed by default, but it should be available or easy to build on most unix variants. If the input is empty, `ifne` does nothing and returns the status 0, which cannot be distinguished from the command running successfully. If you want to do something if the input is empty, you need to arrange for the command not to return 0, which can be done by having the success case return a distinguishable error status:

```
ifne sh -c 'do_stuff_with_input && exit 254'
case $? in
  0) echo empty;;
  254) echo success;;
  *) echo failure;;
esac
```

`test -t 0` has nothing to do with this; it tests whether standard input is a terminal. It doesn't say anything one way or the other as to whether any input is available.

Here with 254 chosen arbitrarily, avoiding 255 as commands doing some `exit(-1)` (which usually result in `$?` being 255) are relatively common (`-exec(-2)` less so).

Comment: On systems with STREAMS based pipes (Solaris HP/UX), I believeve you can use the I_PEEK ioctl to peek at what's on a pipe without consuming it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas unfortunately there's no way to peek data from a pipe/fifo on \*BSD, so no perspective to implement a *portable* `peek` utility which could return the actual data from a pipe, not just how much of it there is. (in 4.4 BSD, 386BSD etc pipes were implemented as [socket pairs](https://github.com/denghuancong/4.4BSD-Lite/blob/c995ba982d79d1ccaa1e8446d042f4c7f0442d5f/usr/src/sys/kern/uipc_syscalls.c#L971), but that was gutted in later versions of *BSD -- though they kept them bi-directional).

Comment: From my brief testing it looks like this will hang if the pipe is open but there is no data available, as is common when running the script from a terminal.

Comment: @NathanArthur Yes, it will. That's part of the requirement. If you open a pipe and there's no data on it now, how do you know whether it's because it's an empty pipe or it's because you opened it too early and the other side hasn't started writing yet? The only way to know is to wait until either the writing side writes something, or the writing side closes the pipe.

Answer (score 29):

A simple solution is to use `ifne` command (if input not empty). In some distributions, it is not installed by default. It is a part of the package `moreutils` in most distros.

`ifne` runs a given command if and only if the standard input is not empty

Note that if the standard input is not empty, it is passed through `ifne` to the given command

Comment: As of 2017, it's not there by default in Mac or Ubuntu.

Comment: I installed `ifne` in FreeBSD 11.3 (more specifically, a FreeBSD 11.3 jail in FreeNAS 11.3) using port https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/moreutils/.  I then copied the `ifne` binary to `$HOME/bin` in FreeNAS 11.3 so that I could run it from scripts in FreeNAS home directory.

Answer (score 26):

check if file descriptor of stdin (0) is open or closed:

```
[ ! -t 0 ] && echo "stdin has data" || echo "stdin is empty"
```

Comment: When you pass some data and you want to check if there is some, you pass the FD anyway so this is also not a good test.

Comment: `[ -t 0 ]` checks if fd 0 is opened to a **tty**, not whether it is closed or open.

Comment: @mosvy could you please elaborate on how that would affect using that solution in a script? Are there cases when it doesn't work?

Comment: @JepZ huh? `./that_script </dev/null` => "stdin has data". Or `./that_script <&-` to have the stdin really *closed*.

Answer (score 22):

If you like short and cryptic one-liners:

```
$ echo "string" | grep . && echo "fill" || echo "empty"
string
fill
$ echo "string" | tail -n+2 | grep . && echo "fill" || echo "empty"
empty
```

I used the examples from the original question. If you don't want the piped data use `-q` option with grep

Some commenters rightfully noted that this version will ignore new lines. My answer is focused on the original question. From this point of view a newline symbol is an empty string. Using `grep ^`, as suggested by @EvgEnZh solves this corner case, but I am not sure it is what the requestor wanted. Please, add this variant in comments, it is a useful correction.

Comment: `grep .` is exactly what I was looking for, and it's so simple. Thanks!

Comment: What is the diffrence betwee the two examples? (i.e., the one with tail and the one without).

Comment: `grep` consumes the pipe and blocks when it becomes empty.

Comment: good catch, for text with color: `echo "" | grep --color=never . || echo "empty"`

Comment: @user I used examples from the question. In reality 'echo "string" | tail -n+2' is the same as 'echo ""'

Comment: `echo` will still put a newline. You need `echo -n ''`

Answer (score 16):

Old question, but in case someone comes across it as I did: My solution is to read with a timeout.

```
while read -t 5 line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

If `stdin` is empty, this will return after 5 seconds. Otherwise it will read all the input and you can process it as needed.

In these situations where `-t` is supported, you can test for input before reading any data with `-t0`. (also specifying `-u0` for STDIN because awslinux needs it, whereas ubuntu assumes it)

```
if [ $(read -u0 -t0) ]; then ....
```

And you can start reading as normal afterward

from `help read`:

> If TIMEOUT is 0, read returns immediately, without trying to read any data, returning success only if input is available on the specified file descriptor.

Comment: While I like the idea, `-t` is sadly not part of POSIX: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html

Comment: +1 for considering timeouts.

Answer (score 11):

One easy way to check if there's data available for reading in Unix is with the `FIONREAD` ioctl.

I cannot think of any standard utility doing just that, so here is a trivial program doing it (better than the `ifne` from moreutils IMHO ;-)).

```
fionread [ prog args ... ]
```

If there's no data available on stdin, it will exit with status 1. If there's data, it will run `prog`. If no `prog` is given, it will exit with status 0.

This should work with most kinds of file descriptors, not just pipes.

**fionread.c**

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#ifdef __sun
#include <sys/filio.h>
#endif
#include <err.h>

int main(int ac, char **av){
        int r; struct pollfd pd = { 0, POLLIN };
        if(poll(&pd, 1, -1) < 0) err(1, "poll");
        if(ioctl(0, FIONREAD, &r)) err(1, "ioctl(FIONREAD)");
        if(r < 1) return 1;
        if(++av, --ac < 1) return 0;
        execvp(*av, av);
        err(1, "execvp %s", *av);
}
```

Comment: Does this program actually work? Don't you need to wait for a `POLLHUP` event as well to handle the empty case? Does that work if there are multiple file descriptions on the other end of the pipe?

Comment: Yes it works. POLLHUP is only returned by poll, you should use POLLIN to wait for a POLLHUP. It doesn't matter how many open handles are to any end of the pipe.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=FIONREAD+user%3A22565 for how to run FIONREAD from perl (more commonly available than compilers)

Comment: Why is this better than `ifne` from moreutils?

Comment: @DerekMahar Because a) it's much smaller b) much faster c) it's a single process, it execs through to the command directly.

Comment: @DerekMahar d) it doesn't change the _nature_ of the stdin passed to `cmd`; eg. if the stdin is a socket, `cmd` would still be able to call `getpeername(2)` on it to see who's at the end of the connection. As mentioned by Stéphane Chazelas, you can trivially do this in perl, python, ruby, etc. Not in the shell or with any standard utilities, though.

Comment: @mosvy The code may be smaller (I haven't checked `ifne.c`), but at least on FreeBSD 11.3, the default binary that `gcc` builds from `fionread.c` is larger (`fionread` is 7896 bytes and `ifne` is 7440 bytes).

Comment: @DerekMahar Strip it. `cc -s ...` or `strip a.out` afterwards.

Comment: @mosvy, okay, that reduced the size of binary `fionread` to 5456 bytes, 1984 bytes smaller than `ifne`.  My 3 TB hard drive is grateful! :)

Comment: fwiw binary sizes should be compared with the `size(1)` utility, and take into account the initialization crtX.o code. I've just compiled the silly thing on FreeBSD 12.1 and it came out 549 bytes larger than `int main(){}` (~4.8 times smaller than `ifne` ;-))

Comment: @mosvy I just ran `size(1)` on each binary, but I'll admit that I don't know how to interpret the output.

Comment: @DerekMahar it's the 4th column: the sum of text (= code, machine instructions) + data (= initialized static vars) + [bss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) (= non-initialized static vars) _in decimal_. Of course, a program may appear deceptively small, either because it depends on a lot of shared libraries that nobody else is using (`ldd` it) or because it bloats itself at runtime by doing a lot of non-transient dynamic allocations. Not the case with either `ifne` or my little example, they all depend on just `libc.so`, which is 100% sure already mapped in memory by the time they're run.

Comment: `size fionread` => 2691 bytes and `size /usr/local/bin/ifne` => 4479 bytes

Comment: Why `FIONREAD` and not just `poll()`?

Answer (score 6):

In bash:

```
read -t 0
```

Detects if an input has data (without reading anything). Then you can read the input (if the input is available at the time the read is executed):

```
if     read -t 0
then   read -r input
       echo "got input: $input"
else   echo "No data to read"
fi
```

---

**Note:** Understand that this depends on timing. This detects if input already has data only at the time `read -t` runs.

For example, with

```
{ sleep 0.1; echo "abc"; } | read -t 0; echo "$?"
```

the output is `1` (read failure, i.e.: empty input). The echo writes some data but is not very fast to start and write its first byte, thus, `read -t 0` will report that its input is empty, since program has not written anything yet.

Comment: https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/64447609994bfddeef1061948022c074093e9a9f/lib/sh/input_avail.c#L62 - here is source of how bash detects that something is in file descriptor.

Comment: @PavelPatrin [That does not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/how-to-check-if-a-pipe-is-empty-and-run-a-command-on-the-data-if-it-isnt/498065?noredirect=1#comment916641_497121). As clearly seen from your link, `bash` will either do a `select()` or an `ioctl(FIONREAD)`, or neither of them, but not both, as it should for it to work. `read -t0` is broken. [Do not use it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/how-to-check-if-a-pipe-is-empty-and-run-a-command-on-the-data-if-it-isnt/498065?noredirect=1#comment916652_497121)

Answer (score 4):

You may use `test -s /dev/stdin` (in an explicit subshell) as well.

```
# test if a pipe is empty or not
echo "string" | 
    (test -s /dev/stdin && echo 'pipe has data' && cat || echo 'pipe is empty')

echo "string" | tail -n+2 | 
    (test -s /dev/stdin && echo 'pipe has data' && cat || echo 'pipe is empty')

: | (test -s /dev/stdin && echo 'pipe has data' && cat || echo 'pipe is empty')
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Always says pipe is empty.

Comment: Works on my Mac, but not on my Linux box.

Answer (score 4):

If you need this functionality for use in xargs and you have GNU xargs, you can use `xargs -r`. Ex. curl won't run here:

```
echo -n '' | xargs -r curl
```

Comment: There's a lot of answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296710/how-to-ignore-xargs-commands-if-stdin-input-is-empty) on how to do this on non GNU xargs

Answer (score 2):

The following approach worked like a charm for me:

```
function _read_from_stdin() {
  less <&0 2>/dev/null
}
```

It reads from STDIN and returns its contents (if any).
All you need to do afterwards is to check if contents is empty:

```
stdin_contents="$(_read_from_stdin)"

if [[ ! "${stdin_contents}" ]] ; then
  echo "STDIN is empty!"
else
  echo "Have something in STDIN: ${stdin_contents}"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

## Full POSIX solution

Compile the following file containing a call to [`poll()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html) into a binary called `has_data`:

```c
#include <poll.h>
int main() {
    struct pollfd fds = { 0, POLLIN, 0};
    poll(&fds, 1, -1);
    return fds.revents & POLLIN ? 0 : 1;
}
```

`gcc -o has_data has_data.c`

## Usage

### with a [pipeline](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02)

*`cat` only runs if `has_data` succeeds*

```bash
echo foobar | ( has_data && cat ) | ...
```

### with a file descriptor

***N** is the number of the file descriptor opened in the current Shell Execution Environment*

```bash
if has_data <&N; then
    echo "Has data"
fi
```

### with a filename

```bash
if has_data <filename; then
    echo "Has data"
fi
```

**There is a problem with this approach when `filename` is a [FIFO](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkfifo.html), though.** According to [the documentation of `close`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html):

> When all file descriptors associated with a pipe or FIFO special file are closed, any data remaining in the pipe or FIFO shall be discarded.

This means that when `has_data` closes the FIFO file and the file is not opened by another process, the data yet to be read will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Another hack that you can try is using `timeout` to read from `/dev/stdin` like this:

```bsh
timeout 1s cat /dev/stdin > /tmp/input
if [ $? -eq 124 ] && ! [ -s /tmp/input ]
then
  echo "No input provided."
else
  echo "Input provided"
  # Optionally, you can move or read from /tmp/input...whatever your program needs to do.
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Use grep

```
chris@SR-ENG-P18 /cygdrive/c/Projects
$ ( ! echo -n "" | grep -q '.' && echo "empty" || echo "fill" )
empty

chris@SR-ENG-P18 /cygdrive/c/Projects
$ ( ! echo -n "string" | grep -q '.' && echo "empty" || echo "fill" )
fill
```

`grep` will return 1 (i.e. error) when nothing is matched.  You want the opposite thus the not operator `!`.

Be sure to use `echo -n ""` in your testing because `echo ""` will output a newline.

Comment: `grep` will consume the pipe and block when it becomes empty. Also [there is a grep answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509498/454969) already.

Comment: @EvgenKo423, that answer makes no attempt to explain why this works.  1 for false and 0 for true is a subtlety that needs to be explained.

Comment: Please note that if you have some minor improvements for a question or answer, you should use Edit.

Answer (score 1):

I find the following is the most elegant, I use it in scripts:

```bash
function isempty {
    ifne false
}

function isnotempty {
    ifne -n false
}
```

It uses `ifne` from moreutils, as others already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a reasonable ifne implementation in bash if you're ok with reading the whole first line

```
ifne () {
        read line || return 1
        (echo "$line"; cat) | eval "$@"
}


echo hi | ifne xargs echo hi =
cat /dev/null | ifne xargs echo should not echo
```

Comment: `read` will also return _false_ if the input is non-empty but contains no newline character, `read` does some processing on its input and may read more than one line unless you call it as `IFS= read -r line`. `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using `read -rt 0`

example from original question, with no data:

```
echo "string" | tail -n+2 | if read -rt 0 ; then echo has data ; else echo no data ; fi
```

Comment: no, that doesn't work. try with `{ sleep .1; echo yes; } | { read -rt0 || echo NO; cat; }` (false negative) and `true | { sleep .1; read -rt0 && echo YES; }` (false positive). In fact, bash's `read` will be fooled even by fds opened in **write-only** mode: `{ read -rt0 && echo YES; cat; } 0>/tmp/foo`. The only thing it seem to do is a `select(2)` on that fd.

Comment: ... and `select` will return a fd as "ready" if a `read(2)` on it would not block, no matter if it will return `EOF` or an error. Conclusion: `read -t0` is **broken** in `bash`. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is reformulating the problem as a pure problem of running a command with the input from a stream and massaging that stream to fit your use case. Ie, you want a command to operate on a stream of data and this data may come from `stdin` **and**/**or** *another stream(s)*.

#### AND

If its `stdin` **and** another stream it should be pretty straightforward using `cat`

```bash
echo bar |
  cat - <(echo biz) |
  cat -A
# output: bar$biz$
```

This will pipe the contents of `stdin` **and** the output of the process substitution `echo bar` to the `stdin` of `cat -A`.

#### OR

**Or** on the other hand is a bit trickier. Let's say you want to run a command with input from `stdin` but fallback to something else if nothing was passed to `stdin`.

In this case an approach is reformulate the problem as combining streams (including a delimiter sequence say two null-bytes) and sinking the stream IFF `stdin` is non-empty by using `sed` and matching the delimiter in the combined stream.

```bash
echo bar |
  cat - <(printf '\x0\x0\n') <(echo biz) |
  sed \
    -e '1{/\x0\x0/s@@@;N;s@\n@@}' \
    -e '1!{/\x0\x0/s@@@;q}' | # stdin was non-empty, sink the rest
    cat -A
# output: bar$


< /dev/null |
  cat - <(printf '\x0\x0\n') <(echo biz) |
  sed \
    -e '1{/\x0\x0/s@@@;N;s@\n@@}' \
    -e '1!{/\x0\x0/s@@@;q}' | # stdin was non-empty, sink the rest
    cat -A
# output: biz$
```

We can combine this approach with `xargs -I%` for an additional fallback. It uses process substitution but other than that it should be pretty POSIX compatible.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# This script takes a list of paths from stdin
# IFF it's empty the list of files is the existing file 'foo'
# Each file and/or directory in this list is passed to stat
# IFF this list is empty we run stat on the current directory

combined_stream() {
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    cat <(printf '\x0\x0\n') <(find foo -type f 2> /dev/null)
  else
    cat - <(printf '\x0\x0\n') <(find foo -type f 2> /dev/null)
  fi
}

combined_stream |
  sed \
    -e '1{/\x0\x0/s@@@;N;s@\n@@}' \
    -e '1!{/\x0\x0/s@@@;q}' | # stdin was non-empty, sink the rest
  xargs -I% stat % |
  grep . || stat .
```

Answer (score 0):

Is more difficult to be achieved on C Shell, but I made it.

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

while 1
  head -c1 | sed p | \
  ( exit ( ! `head -c1 | wc -c` ) && \
  tail -c1 ) || exit
end
```

Also achievable on Bourne Shells, though I think may not be the best solution.

```
#!/bin/sh

while :
do
  head -c1 | sed p | \
  ( ! ( exit `head -c1 | wc -c` ) && \
  tail -c1 ) || exit
done
```

Answer (score -1):

### Simplest ternary

```bsh
doSomethingAndCheckTruth && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

The right part (after the `&&`) will not run unless the left part is complete, so you only check truth upon successfully running something else, saving computation.

#### Example

using home`brew` and `grep` we check if the `bat` program is installed

- If true you will see "yes"
- If false you will see "no"

I added the `-q` to suppress the `grep`ped string output here, so you only see "yes" or "no"

```bsh
brew list | grep -q bat && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

Tested with `bash` and `zsh`

Comment: Multiple answers here already mention `grep -q ` and `.. && .. || ..`. What does this answer add?

Comment: The Simplest ternary format I've seen so far