# How can I print a conditional header BEFORE stdout, if there is any output on stdout

Tags: shell, text-processing, pipe, email

I have a process that filters a list of files from a directory (having `find` check to see if there are files older than a certain period to show a queue is stuck). It may or may not return anything, and if it does, it is mailed to be by `cron`.

What I would like to know is if there is a program or simple `bash` method to pipe this output to, and if there is *any* output through it, prepend a header line (like "These are the files stuck in the queue").

Comment: Related (not a duplicate, I voted to close then realized this was mistaken): [How to check if pipe is empty](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33049) for when you want to do something different when the input is empty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sed inline answer:

```
find ./files -mtime +90|sed '1s/^/Files stuck in queue:\n/'
```

Comment: This works, and is what I ended up using.

Comment: @silvein: It seems **short** is your main criterion, so here are a couple of points: *camh's* `awk` answer can be tweaked to being only 8 chars longer than sed (above): `awk 'NR==1{print "header"}1'`... but **even shorter** than above, by 5 chars, is:  `sed "1i header"`

Comment: @Peter.O As with all things Unix-y, there are multiple ways to do something. But the likelihood that I can remember it increases if it is shorter.

Answer (score 5):

Since the other methods don't actually provide a `bash` method, as was asked for:

```
command | while IFS= read -r line; do
    (( i )) || { printf '%s\n' 'These are the files stuck in the queue:' ; (( i++ )) ; }
    printf '%s\n' "${line}"
done
```

All of the commands used are internal to `bash`.

If there are no lines of output, nothing will be printed. If there are, the header line will be printed, and then the output from `command`.

Comment: This worked, and has the advantage of being all `bash`.

Answer (score 4):

When I find I want to keep state when processing an input stream, I find awk is often the best tool to use.

In this case, you want to process a stream, and if you see some input, write out a header and record that you have written the header.

```
awk '!input_seen { print "header"; input_seen = 1 } 1'
```

This will print a header if the variable `input_seen` is false (which it defaults to if undefined) and sets it to a truth value (1). The `1` at the end is another rule which is a short-hand way of saying: print the current line - you could also replace the `1` with `{ print }`.

Comment: This worked, and I would have used it but it is a little longer than the `sed` version.

Answer (score 0):

Or,

```
output=$(command)
[[ -n $output ]] && { echo "header"; echo "$output"; }
```