# Exiting a pipeline if a former command fails

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to check the number of running and queued PBS jobs by parsing the output of `qstat -tn1` from a `bash` script.
So far, this has worked:

```
count ()
{
    qstat -tn1 | awk '
        BEGIN { R = 0; Q = 0; }
        $10 == "R" { R++ }
        $10 == "Q" { Q++ }
        END { print R, Q }'
}

if read -r R Q < <(count)
    ...
```

However, I see that `qstat` occasionally fails for unknown reasons. In that case, it prints nothing to `stdout` and some error message to `stderr`, and exits with a non-zero status (fairly standard). However, `awk` doesn't know that `qstat` failed, and happily prints `0 0` for the empty input it received. Then `read` assigns 0 to both `R` and `Q` without knowing that `qstat` actually failed.

1. I need to initialize `R` and `Q` with 0 in the `BEGIN` block of the `awk` script, because there may be no running processes or no queued processes, and I need to print `0`, not just an empty string, for the number of such processes.
2. I could do `set -o pipefail`, which would allow `count` to exit with a non-zero status, but `read` cannot see the exit status, and `awk` gets executed and prints `0 0` for the empty input anyway.
3. I could try a named pipe and subprocesses, but having to manage them feels like an overkill too complicated.

Is there any good way to allow the caller of `count` to detect its failure?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/985876/51831 and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2413166/51831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think reading `count` in a process substitution prevents you from obtaining its return status. So don't do it. Instead, store the result in a variable, or use a pipe.

```
count=$(count)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  read -r R Q <<<"$count"
  …
```

or

```
set -o pipefail
if count | { read -r R Q; … }
```

Another possibility is to use the `PIPESTATUS` variable to check the return status of the first command.

```
count=$(qstat -tn1 | awk …)
if ((${PIPESTATUS[0]} == 0)); then
  read P Q
  …
```

Alternatively, arrange for the awk to print something distinctive (e.g. nothing) when its input is empty.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { R = 0; Q = 0; }
    $10 == "R" { R++ }
    $10 == "Q" { Q++ }
    END { if (NR) print R, Q }'
```

You can test if the input of a command is empty with `ifne` from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) or [other methods](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/how-to-check-if-pipe-is-empty). But since you're piping into awk, you might as well do it right inside the awk script that you already have.

If you need to get the return status from the `qstat` command, you can feed it to awk as an extra input line. For easier parsing, arrange for the last line to have a unique format.

```
{
  qstat -tn1
  echo exit_code = $?
} | awk '
    …
    /^exit_code = / { status = $3 }
    END { if (status == 0) print Q, R }
'
```

Comment: Doesn't `count | { read -r R Q; … }` execute `read` in a subshell? I tried `echo 2 3 | { read -r R Q; }; echo $R $Q` and it prints out nothing. I like the answer using `<<<"$count"`, though.

Comment: Testing whether the input is empty (either with `if (NR)` or with ifne`) is not good, since `qstat` can really output nothing and exit successfully if there are no processes.

Comment: @musiphil Yes. Put whatever uses `$R` and `$Q` inside the braces, e.g. `count | { read -r R Q; echo $R $Q; }`

Comment: I need to use the values of the variables in future statements, which is why I used process substitution in the beginning. `count | { read -r R Q; echo $R $Q; }` is barely different from `count`.

Comment: @musiphil Another method is to filter the exit code inside awk.

Comment: Another trick is: `{ qstat -tn1 && echo "SUCCESS"; } | awk '
BEGIN { R = 0; Q = 0; }
$10 == "R" { R++ }
$10 == "Q" { Q++ }
$0 == "SUCCESS" { print R, Q }'`

Comment: Passing the exit status through the pipe is a nice trick, though it may not be fully generalizable (i.e. we may not be able to distinguish our "special code" if the stream transferred through the pipe can be of an arbitrary format). I'm settling on what I wrote in the previous comment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @musiphil You used the same “special code” — `SUCCESS`, included only when the exit code is 0. If you can't make the last line unambiguous, modify the awk script so that it treats the last line specially, and then you simply `echo $?` after the input-producing command.

Comment: Yes, I know that I used a special code and that the my trick above is not fully generalizable; I was criticizing my own solution. ;-) It would be nice to have a separate channel to pass the exit status, but for this particular problem, the special code works well enough.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
count ()
{
    { qstat -tn1 || echo "EPIC FAIL" } | awk '
        BEGIN { R = 0; Q = 0; }
        $10 == "R" { R++ }
        $10 == "Q" { Q++ }
        END { print R, Q }'
}

if read -r R Q < <(count)
    ...
```

If `qstat` is successful its output is sent to `awk`. If `qstat` returns non-zero status the text "EPIC FAIL" is sent to `awk`.

This is just an example. Replace the echo with something appropriate that you can handle inside `awk` or with `if read`.

Comment: `A || B | C` binds like `A || { B | C; }`, so if `A` succeeds then neither `B` nor `C` is executed. However, `{ A || B; } | C` is a working solution; thanks for the idea.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've done it recently with `a || b && c`, which binds like `{ a || b } && c` which is why it didn't occur to me. Updated.

Comment: A variant of the idea is to print and detect something that indicates success: `{ qstat -tn1 && echo SUCCESS; } | awk '... $0 == "SUCCESS" { print... }'`