# make find fail when nothing was found

Tags: find, exit-status

When `find` is invoked to find nothing, it still exits with code 0. Is there a way to make it return an exit code indicating failure when no file was found?

Comment: I don't think `find` directly supports it. You can do something like `find ... -print0 | grep -qz .`, perhaps, if your `grep` supports it.

Comment: My grep is gnu grep so it supports this nice idea. Unfortunately, I also need the find output to be piped somewhere and I cannot replace the pipe with `-exec`.

Comment: I'm making something.

Comment: @XZS you can skip the `-q`, then `grep` will simply pass through the data, while still breaking the pipeline and reporting a failure if nothing comes through.

Comment: @muru A do-nothing grep guarding the pipe, very elegant. Turn this into an answer and it will be accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your `grep` supports reading NUL-delimited lines (like GNU `grep` with `-z`), you can use it to test if anything was output by `find`:

```
find /some/path -print0 | grep -qz .
```

To pipe the data to another command, you can remove the `-q` option, letting `grep` pass on the data unaltered while still reporting an error if nothing came through:

```
find /some/path -print0 | grep -z . | ...
```

Specifically, `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` in bash should hold the exit status of `grep`.

If your `find` doesn't support `-print0`, the use grep without `-z` and hope that newlines in filenames don't cause problems:

```
find ... | grep '^' | ...
```

In this case, using `^` instead of `.` might be safer. If output has consecutive newlines, `^` will pass them by, but `.` won't.

Comment: Grep's `-z` is a GNU extension. Do you have something for more Posixy?

Comment: @jww unlikely, since with pure POSIX, I don't think you can detect a failure in the middle of a shell pipe. If you have a shell which can do that (via `PIPE_STATUS` or something similar), then it probably has a `read` which can do null-delimited input; then you can read a single line, fail if empty; or print it back out and `cat` the rest. (Assuming you want to pass on the data to something else, otherwise you can probably do `find ... -exec echo foo {} \+ | grep -q foo`.)

Comment: Is `-z` just to make sure strange characters like `\r` are preserved?  If piping through grep isn't desired, or there are no weird filenames, then is `grep -z` needed?

Answer (score 4):

You ask specifically for a return code... which I don't see in options. But this is how I solved it (because `grep -z` is not on Mac port):

Gives code 0 if 1 line was found

```
test 1 == `find */.kitchen/ -name private_key | wc -l`
```

So...

```
if [ 0 == `find */.kitchen/ -name my-file.txt | wc -l` ] ; then
   echo "Nothing found"; exit;
fi
```

---

Also, as a generic solution, this might be useful:

[Check if pipe is empty and run a command on the data if it isn't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/check-if-pipe-is-empty-and-run-a-command-on-the-data-if-it-isnt)

Answer (score 0):

I am very late to this question, but I just found an elegant answer :-)

```
find . -type d -empty -and -not -name . -print -exec rmdir {} + | \
  awk '{print} END {if (NR == 0) {exit(1)}}'
```

`find` here looks for empty directories in the current directory,
removes the empty directories,
prints the name of removed directories to the pipe,
`awk` prints the output of `find` and if no output is found `NR == 0`, bails out with an error code.

This means I can now iteratively remove empty directories:

```
while find . -type d -empty -and -not -name . -print -exec rmdir {} + | \
  awk '{print} END {if (NR == 0) {exit(1)}}'; \
do echo; done
```

Replace "my" `find` parameters with yours, keep the `awk` part either as is or without the `{print}` if you do not want to see the output of `find` in the terminal, and "voilà".