# Elegant way to construct a pipeline based on return value and not exit code?

Tags: shell-script, debian, shell, apt, exit-status

**When the status code is useless, is there anyway to construct a pipeline based on output from stdout?**

I'd prefer the answer not address the use-case but the question in the scope of shell scripting. What I'm trying to do is find the most-specific package available in the repository by guessing the name based on country and language codes.

Take for instance this,

- `$PACKAGE1=hunspell-en-zz`
- `$PACKAGE2=hunspell-en`

The first guess is more appropriate but it may not exist. In this case, I want to return `hunspell-en` (`$PACKAGE2`) because the first option `hunspell-en-zz` (`$PACKAGE1`) does **not** exist.

### pipelines of apt-cache

The command `apt-cache` returns success (which is defined by shell as exit-code zero) whenever the command is able to run (from the docs of `apt-cache`)

> apt-cache returns zero on normal operation, decimal 100 on error.

That makes using the command in a pipeline more difficult. Normally, I expect the package-search equivalent of a 404 to result in an error (as would happen with `curl` or `wget`). I want to search to see if a package exists, and if not **fall back to another package if it exists**.

This returns nothing, as the first command returns success (so the rhs in the `||` never runs)

```
apt-cache search hunspell-en-zz || apt-cache search hunspell-en
```

### `apt-cache search` with two arguments

This returns nothing, as `apt-cache` ANDs its arguments,

```
apt-cache search hunspell-en-zz hunspell-en
```

From the docs of `apt-cache`

> Separate arguments can be used to specify multiple search patterns that are and'ed together.

So as one of those arguments clearly doesn't exist, this returns nothing.

## The question

What is the shell idiom to handle conventions like those found in `apt-cache` where the return code is useless for the task? And success is determined only by the presence of output on STDOUT?

## Similar to

- [make find fail when nothing was found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198254/make-find-fail-when-nothing-was-found)

  > they both stemming from the same problem. The chosen answer there mentions `find -z` which sadly isn't applicable solution here and is use-case specific. There is no mention of an idiom or constructing a pipeline without using null-termination (not an option on `apt-cache`)

Comment: Are you sure that `hunspell-en` exists? Anyway, you can use `apt-cache policy` and grep for `^$PACKAGENAME:`.

Comment: @AlexP these are only examples hunspell-en does not exist because they package with country names, `hunspell-ar` does exist and there are no country-name packages. I need to find the most accurate package for a given country and language.

Comment: `apt-cache policy 'hunspell-en*' | grep '^\S'`.

Comment: "_fall back to another package if it exists_". So if user do `search foo bar` but `foo` doesn't exist, it should print `bar`?

Comment: @nxnev I updated it to be more explicit.

Comment: `find` is just like `apt-cache` in this respect - useless return code, success is based on output.

Comment: Yes, I agree they're both stemming from the same problem. The chosen answer mentions there mentions `-z` which sadly isn't a solution here so the use-case-specific problem isn't applicable. And there is no mention of an idiom or constructing a pipeline without using null-termination (not an option on `apt-cache`)

Comment: @EvanCarroll the null termination is entirely optional. I only used it because it's the safest way to deal with filenames, so one would expect `find` to be used with `-print0` and so grep with `-z`. Since apt-cache isn't giving null-terminated output, you don't need `-z`.

Comment: @muru I did not get that from the answer there at all, but I've clarified here too. That was the trick I was looking for anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function that takes a command and returns true iff it has some output.

```
r() { local x=$("$@"); [ -n "$x" ] && echo "$x"; }

( ( r echo -n ) || echo 'nada' ) | cat      # Prints 'nada'
( ( r echo -n foo ) || echo 'nada' ) | cat  # Prints 'foo'
```

So for this use case it 'll work like this,

```
r apt-cache search hunspell-en-zz || r apt-cache search hunspell-en
```

Comment: Note that `r printf '\n\n\n'` would return false. With shells other than `zsh`, `r printf '\0\0\0'` would also return false. So would `r printf '\0a\0b\0c'` with some shells.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no standard way to deal with those cases where the success of a command is determined by the presence of output. You can write workarounds, though.

For example, you can save the output of the command in a variable and then check if that variable is empty or not:

```
output="$(command)"

if [[ -n "${output}" ]]; then
  # Code to execute if command succeded
else
  # Code to execute if command failed
fi
```

I think this answers the question in a general way, but if we talk about `apt-cache search` some solutions come to my mind.

I have a script which makes package management easier. Some of its functions are these:

```
search() {
  local 'package' 'packages'
  packages="$( apt-cache search '.*' | cut -d ' ' -f '1' | sort )"
  for package; do
    grep -F -i -e "${package}" <<< "${packages}"
  done
}


search_all() {
  local 'package'
  for package; do
    apt-cache search "${package}" | sort
  done
}


search_description() {
  local 'package' 'packages'
  packages="$( apt-cache search '.*' | sort )"
  for package; do
    grep -F -i -e "${package}" <<< "${packages}"
  done
}


search_names_only() {
  local 'package'
  for package; do
    apt-cache search --names-only "${package}" | sort
  done
}
```

These let you to do multiple searches in a single command. For example:

```
$ search hunspell-en-zz hunspell-en
hunspell-en-au
hunspell-en-ca
hunspell-en-gb
hunspell-en-med
hunspell-en-us
hunspell-en-za
```

Every function search the database in a different way, so the results may vary depending of wich function you use:

```
$ search gnome | wc -l
538
$ search_all gnome | wc -l
1322
$ search_description gnome | wc -l
822
$ search_names_only gnome | wc -l
550
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call this elegant but I think it might do the job:

```
search_packages () {
    local packages=($@)
    local results=()
    for package in "${packages[@]}"; do
        results=($(apt-cache -n search "$package"))
        if [[ "${#results[@]}" -eq 0 ]]; then
            echo "$package not found."
        elif [[ "${#results[@]}" -eq 1 ]]; then
            do stuff with "$package"
        else
            echo "Warning! Found multiple packages for ${package}:"
            printf '\t-> %s\n' "${results[@]}"
        fi
    done
}
```

I don't have a debian machine to test on unfortunately.  I've included the `-n` for "names-only" option of `apt-cache` to try and limit the search results as it looks like you are mostly sure of what you are searching.

Can be run like:

```
$ search_packages hunspell-en-zz hunspell-en
$ my_packages=('hunspell-en-zz' 'hunspell-en')
$ search_packages "${my_packages[@]}"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking of doing, however I was looking for something as little bit more elegant, so let's see if anyone has anything else clever (like a more abstract solution away from the use-case) if not I'll mark it as chosen.

Comment: Ideally, apt-cache would just return something less stupid.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, Have you tried messing with the `-q` quiet option?  The man page isn't very verbose on it but maybe it changes the return values?

Comment: still returns 0. =(

Answer (score 2):

Muru clarified this in the comments `grep` will return a status of 1 if there is no input. So you can add `grep .` into the stream and if there is no input to match the pattern `.`, it'll change the status code:

```
( ( echo -n | grep . ) || echo 'nada' ) | cat      # prints 'nada'
( ( echo -n foo | grep . ) || echo 'nada' ) | cat  # prints 'foo'
```

To the use-case that looks like this. In the below, there is no `-pl-pl` so it falls back and returns `hunspell-pl`

```
apt-cache search hunspell-pl-pl | grep . || apt-cache search hunspell-pl
```

Or,

```
apt-cache search hunspell-en-US | grep . || apt-cache search hunspell-en
```

There is an `-en-US` so it returns `hunspell-en-us`.

See also,

- If you're looking for the [bash-specific solution check out this answer by roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413344/3285)

Comment: `grep .` returns true if the input contains at least one (fully delimited with some implementations) line that contains at least one (well formed with most implementations) character and will otherwise remove the empty lines. `grep '^'` would work better at checking that there is some output, though with some implementation could still return false if the input is one non-delimited line (and could remove that line, or with other implementations, return true but add the missing newline). Some grep implementations also choke on the NUL character.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a:

```
has_output() {
  LC_ALL=C awk '1;END{exit!NR}'
}
```

And then:

```
if cmd | has_output; then
  echo cmd did produce some output
fi
```

Some `awk` implementations may choke on NUL characters in the input.

Contrary to `grep '^'`, the above would be guaranteed to work on an input that doesn't end in a newline character, but would add the missing newline.

To avoid that and to be portable to systems where `awk` chokes on NUL, you could use `perl` instead:

```
has_output() {
  perl -pe '}{exit!$.'
}
```

With `perl`, you could also define a variant that handles arbitrary files more gracefully:

```
has_output() {
  PERLIO=:unix perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=\65536} END{exit!$.}'
}
```

That bounds the memory usage (like for files that don't have newline characters like big sparse files).

You could also create variants like:

```
has_at_least_one_non_empty_line() {
  LC_ALL=C awk '$0 != "" {n++};1; END{exit!n}'
}
```

or:

```
has_at_least_one_non_blank_line() {
  awk 'NF {n++};1; END{exit!n}'
}
```

(beware the definition of *blank* varies between `awk` implementations, some where it's limited to space and tab, some where it also includes ASCII vertical spacing characters like CR or FF, some where it considers the locale's blanks)

Ideally, on Linux, you'd want to use the `splice()` system call to maximize performance. I don't know of a command that would expose it but you could always use `python`'s `ctypes`:

```
has_output() {
  python -c 'if 1:
    from ctypes import *
    import sys
    l = CDLL("libc.so.6")
    ret = 1
    while l.splice(0,0,1,0,65536,0) > 0:
      ret = 0
    sys.exit(ret)'
}
```

(note that either `has_output`'s stdin or stdout (or both) has to be a pipe for `splice()` to work).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use very basic builtin functions of the shell:

```
ck_command() { [ -n $("$@") ] ; }
```

Here is the simplest test case:

```
ck_command echo 1 ; echo $?

ck_command echo ; echo $?
```

Then you could easily use it with the `||` construct you are used to:

```
ck_command command_1 || ck_command command_2
```

This simple function will work as you would like with your `apt_cache` behaviour whichever the number of arguments would be.

Comment: Except this loses STDOUT in the process, `ck_command echo 'asdf' | cat` outputs nothing.

Comment: → EvanCarroll: this wasn't in your § "The question". To also achieve this output conservation, look at the very elegant and simple answer from @roaima: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413344/31707 .