# How can a node in a Bash pipeline peek at, but not consume, its input stream?

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

How might a node in a Bash pipeline only peek at, but not consume, its input stream?

For example, how might I modify the following script so that it outputs "print" instead of nothing?  In particular, how might I modify or replace `grep --quiet print` so that it only peeks at, but does not consume, its input?

```
printf "%s\n" a b print c |
  if grep --quiet print
  then
    grep print | cat
  fi
```

Output:

Desired output:

```
print
```

Ideally, I seek a program `peek` that is similar to `grep`, but that doesn't consume its input.  `peek print` would return error code 0 if it finds "print" in the input and if not, returns a non-zero error code.

Here's how `peek` would work in my example:

```
printf "%s\n" a b print c |
  if peek print
  then
    grep print | cat
  fi
```

Output:

```
print
```

The reason I want to do this instead of simply filtering the results with `grep print` is to avoid processing empty search results that might cause an error.

Comment: In the case where your Q is "how can I ran a command (eg. `cvsq`) only if its input (eg. the result of `grep`) is [not empty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/), then you probably don't have to save the entire search result in a variable or tempfile, a single byte should suffice: `PRODUCER | grep PATTERN | { t=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null; printf x); t=${t%x}; [ "$t" ] && { printf '%s' "$t"; cat; } | CONSUMER; }`

Comment: That's an interesting solution.  Can you break it down for me?

Comment: I think I see how your script works.  It reads a single byte from the input stream and then pipes this byte and the rest of the input stream to the consumer only if the original input has at least one byte.

Comment: It's basically the same thing as the accepted answer from the linked Q, only simplified a bit (it won't handle NUL bytes in the input). In fact, you really can _peek_ at a pipe in linux with the `tee(2)` system call, but there's no generally available shell utility that can use it, so the only thing left are such hacks.

Comment: @mosvy, if you were to promote your [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565581/how-can-a-node-in-a-bash-pipeline-peek-at-but-not-consume-its-input-stream/565591?noredirect=1#comment1051757_565581) to an answer, I would accept it as the answer.

Comment: I don't think my solution is different enough from the accepted answer from the linked Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight forward approach I can think of is to use a temporary storage for output. It can be done with minimal modification of your code like this:

```
atmp=$(mktemp "/tmp/XXXXXX")

printf "%s\n" a b print c | tee $atmp | 
  if grep --quiet print
  then
    grep print $atmp 
  fi  
rm $atmp #cleanup
```

For small volumes of output that may be acceptable.

Comment: I'm not able to grasp the purpose of this. Why not just `print ... > "$atmp"; grep print "$atmp"` ? ;-)

Comment: No difference if all you need is to get the grepped line printed. The question was phrased more generally about reusing the output.

Comment: @mosvy I want to avoid processing empty search results.  In my specific case, the search results may include CSV rows, including a header, which the script subsequently passes to `csvq` to filter the CSV rows.  In the event that the search finds no CSV rows and no header, `csvq` reports an error which I want to avoid.

Comment: @DerekMahar you should give a better, more complete example

Comment: @mosvy I think my example captures the essence of what I want to achieve, though stating more clearly why I wanted to do this might have been beneficial.

Comment: @mosvy I made changes to my question that I hope clarify my goal.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it addressed the question more than the specific example.

Comment: Two of three users rejected my [suggested edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/325356), so I will post it here instead: `atmp=$(mktemp "/tmp/XXXXXX"); printf "%s\n" a b print c | if grep print > $atmp; then cat $atmp; fi; rm $atmp #cleanup;`.  This stores only the search results of `grep print` instead of all of the original input.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach similar to @Tagwint's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565585/5783) is to store the result of `grep print` in a shell variable and then print the contents of that variable only if there are search results:

```
printf "%s\n" a print b print c |
 if result=$(grep print)
 then
   echo "$result";
 fi
```

Output:

```
print
print
```

This would be acceptable where the search results are not too large.

Comment: how's that different from `printf '%s\n' .. | grep print`?

Comment: See @Tagwint's comment at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565581/how-can-a-node-in-a-bash-pipeline-peek-at-but-not-consume-its-input-stream/565591?noredirect=1#comment1051730_565585 and my comment at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565581/how-can-a-node-in-a-bash-pipeline-peek-at-but-not-consume-its-input-stream/565591?noredirect=1#comment1051732_565585.

Answer (score 0):

While not a standard Unix utility or Bash script, I decided to solve the problem in this specific example using [`ifne`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ifne) from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
printf "%s\n" a b print c | grep print | ifne echo found
```

Output:

```
found
```

```
printf "%s\n" a b c | grep print | ifne echo found
```

Output:

[@Nick Wirth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/180681/nick-wirth) referred to `lfne` in his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297228/5783) to [*How to check if a pipe is empty and run a command on the data if it isn't?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/how-to-check-if-a-pipe-is-empty-and-run-a-command-on-the-data-if-it-isnt).

Thank you to [@mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy) for [referring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565581/how-can-a-node-in-a-bash-pipeline-peek-at-but-not-consume-its-input-stream?noredirect=1#comment1051757_565581) me to this existing question.

Comment: I can't also accept this answer, but it gets honorable mention because it solves the problem that the example in the question raises using handy tool `ifle` from package moreutils.

Answer (score 0):

I also solved the problem in this specific example using `fionread` which [@mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy) implemented in his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498065/5783) to [*How to check if a pipe is empty and run a command on the data if it isn't?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/how-to-check-if-a-pipe-is-empty-and-run-a-command-on-the-data-if-it-isnt).

```
printf "%s\n" a b print c | grep print | ./fionread echo found
```

Output:

```
found
```

```
printf "%s\n" a b c | grep print | ./fionread echo found
```

Output:

Note that `gcc` easily compiles `fionread.c` on FreeBSD 11.3:

```
$ gcc -o fionread fionread.c
$ echo test | grep test | ./fionread echo found
found
$ echo | grep test | ./fionread echo found
$
```

Comment: I can't also accept this answer, but it gets honorable mention because it solves the problem that the example in the question raised and because `fionread` is a useful tool and smaller than `ifle` from package moreutils.