# Bash - Check if the standard input contains anything

Tags: bash, shell, stdin

I know this question has been asked several times but it seems ineffective in my case.

`[[ ! -t 0 ]]` = Does standard input contains anything?

This command:

```
echo 'Hello world' | [[ ! -t 0 ]]
echo $?
```

gives the correct output: `0`, i.e. the standard input contains anything.
This command:

```
[[ ! -t 0 ]]
echo $?
```

gives the correct output: `1`, i.e. the standard input is empty.
Instead this command:

```
: | [[ ! -t 0 ]]
echo $?
```

gives unexpected output: `0`, when instead the standard input is empty: `1`.

Why does it behave this way and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: You're probably looking for something like [ifne](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/moreutils/ifne.1.en.html) - see for example [How to check if a pipe is empty and run a command on the data if it isn't?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33055/65304)

Comment: ifne is not flexible and forces me to do an if then, instead I need it to give me a simple exit code so I can do an if then else.

Answer (score 3):

> `[[ ! -t 0 ]]` = Does standard input contains anything?

Your premise is wrong. This tests whether *stdin* is connected to a terminal/tty, not whether *stdin* contains anything. Because of the negation the command returns 0 (true) if *stdin* is not connected to a terminal.

See `man test`:

> **`-t FD`** file descriptor `FD` is opened on a terminal

and `man bash`:

> **`-t fd`** True if file descriptor `fd` is open and refers to a terminal.

With this in mind, re-evaluate your examples and you'll see they do indeed return the expected exit status.

The correct way to check if there's anything pending on *stdin* would be to use `select(2)`, but that's not directly available in a shell such as `bash`. The closest I can suggest is to use `read` with an immediate timeout:

```
sleep 2
if read -t 0 _
then
    echo "Ready to receive data"
    IFS= read -r data
    echo "Received: $data"
fi
```

Run this, and then during the initial `sleep`, (a) try preloading *stdin* with some text, (b) do nothing.

Note that this will still hang (on the `read -t 0 _`) if you're reading from a pipe and there is no writer present. It will work as I've described if there is a writer present, even if that writer has not written anything to read.