# How do I break up a file like split to stdout for piping to a command?

Tags: shell, text-processing, stdout, split

I have a large `.sql` file full of `SELECT` statements that contain data I want to insert into my SQL Server database. I'm looking for how I could basically take the file's contents, 100 lines at a time, and pass it to the commands I have set to do the rest.

Basically, I'm looking for `split` that will output to `stdout`, not files.

I'm also using CygWin on Windows, so I don't have access to the full suite of tools.

Comment: Have you looked at using `BULK INSERT`? Separate the data from the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with something that's seemingly gross, if there's a better way please post it:

```
#!/bin/sh

DONE=false
until $DONE; do
    for i in $(seq 1 $2); do 
        read line || DONE=true;
        [ -z "$line" ] && continue;
        lines+=$line$'\n';
    done
    sql=${lines::${#lines}-10}
    (cat "Header.sql"; echo "$sql";) | sqlcmd
    #echo "--- PROCESSED ---";
    lines=;
done < $1
```

Run with `./insert.sh "File.sql" 100` where the 100 is the number of lines to process at a time.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what assumptions are safe with SQL, but for general safety you should do `IFS= read -r line`. Consider the different between `echo ' \t\e\s\t ' | { read line; echo "[$line]"; }` and `echo ' \t\e\s\t ' | { IFS= read -r line; echo "[$line]"; }`. Also `echo` is not safe with arbitrary strings (eg `line="-n"; echo "$line"`), it is safer to use `printf '%s\n`.

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way to do this is:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  { printf '%s\n' "$line"; head -n 99; } |
  other_commands
done <database_file
```

You need to use `read` for the first line in each section as there appears to be no other way to stop when the end of the file is reached. For more information see:

- [Check if pipe is empty and run a command on the data if it isn't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/how-to-check-if-pipe-is-empty)
- [How to pipe output from one process to another but only execute if the first has output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13326/how-to-pipe-output-from-one-process-to-another-but-only-execute-if-the-first-has)

Answer (score 5):

> Basically, I'm looking for `split` that will output to `stdout`, not
>   files.

If you have access to `gnu split`, the `--filter` option does exactly that:

```
‘--filter=command’

    With this option, rather than simply writing to each output file, write
    through a pipe to the specified shell command for each output file.
```

---

So in your case, you could either use those commands with `--filter`, e.g.

```
split -l 100 --filter='{ cat Header.sql; cat; } | sqlcmd; printf %s\\n DONE' infile
```

or write a script, e.g. `myscript`:

```
#!/bin/sh

{ cat Header.sql; cat; } | sqlcmd
printf %s\\n '--- PROCESSED ---'
```

and then simply run

```
split -l 100 --filter=./myscript infile
```

Answer (score 2):

```
_linc() ( ${sh-da}sh ${dbg+-vx} 4<&0 <&3 ) 3<<-ARGS 3<<\CMD
        set -- $( [ $((i=${1%%*[!0-9]*}-1)) -gt 1 ] && {
                shift && echo "\${inc=$i}" ; }
        unset cmd ; [ $# -gt 0 ] || cmd='echo incr "#$((i=i+1))" ; cat'
        printf '%s ' 'me=$$ ;' \
        '_cmd() {' '${dbg+set -vx ;}' "$@" "$cmd" '
        }' )
        ARGS
        s= ; sed -f - <<-INC /dev/fd/4 | . /dev/stdin
                i_cmd <<"${s:=${me}SPLIT${me}}"
                ${inc:+$(printf '$!n\n%.0b' `seq $inc`)}
                a$s
        INC
CMD
```

The above function uses `sed` to apply its argument list as a command string to an arbitrary line increment. The commands you specify on the command line are sourced into a temporary shell function which is fed a here document on stdin consisting of every increment's step worth of lines.

You use it like this:

```
time printf 'this is line #%d\n' `seq 1000` |
_linc 193 sed -e \$= -e r \- \| tail -n2
    #output
193
this is line #193
193
this is line #386
193
this is line #579
193
this is line #772
193
this is line #965
35
this is line #1000
printf 'this is line #%d\n' `seq 1000`  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.004 total
```

The mechanism here is very simple:

```
i_cmd <<"${s:=${me}SPLIT${me}}"
${inc:+$(printf '$!n\n%.0b' `seq $inc`)}
a$s
```

That's the `sed` script. Basically we just `printf $increment * n;`. So if you set your increment to 100 `printf` will write you a `sed` script consisting of 100 lines that say only `$!n`, one `insert` line for the top end of the here-doc, and one `append` for the bottom line - that's it. Most of the rest just handles options.

The `n`ext command tells `sed` to print the current line, delete it, and pull in the next one. The `$!` specifies that it should only try on any line but the last.

Provided only an incrementer it will:

```
printf 'this is line #%d\n' `seq 10` |                                  ⏎
_linc 3
    #output
incr #1
this is line #1
this is line #2
this is line #3
incr #2
this is line #4
this is line #5
this is line #6
incr #3
this is line #7
this is line #8
this is line #9
incr #4
this is line #10
```

So what's happening behind the scenes here is the function is set to `echo` a counter and `cat` its input if not provided a command string. If you saw it on the command line it would look like:

```
{ echo "incr #$((i=i+1))" ; cat ; } <<HEREDOC
this is line #7
this is line #8
this is line #9
HEREDOC
```

It executes one of these for every increment. Look:

```
printf 'this is line #%d\n' `seq 10` |
dbg= _linc 3
    #output
set -- ${inc=2}
+ set -- 2
me=$$ ; _cmd() { ${dbg+set -vx ;} echo incr "#$((i=i+1))" ; cat
}
+ me=19396
        s= ; sed -f - <<-INC /dev/fd/4 | . /dev/stdin
                i_cmd <<"${s:=${me}SPLIT${me}}"
                ${inc:+$(printf '$!n\n%.0b' `seq $inc`)}
                a$s
        INC
+ s=
+ . /dev/stdin
+ seq 2
+ printf $!n\n%.0b 1 2
+ sed -f - /dev/fd/4
_cmd <<"19396SPLIT19396"
this is line #1
this is line #2
this is line #3
19396SPLIT19396
+ _cmd
+ set -vx ; echo incr #1
+ cat
this is line #1
this is line #2
this is line #3
_cmd <<"19396SPLIT19396"
```

### REALLY FAST

```
time yes | sed = | sed -n 'p;n' |
_linc 4000 'printf "current line and char count\n"
    sed "1w /dev/fd/2" | wc -c
    [ $((i=i+1)) -ge 5000 ] && kill "$me" || echo "$i"'

    #OUTPUT

current line and char count
19992001
36000
4999
current line and char count
19996001
36000
current line and char count
[2]    17113 terminated  yes |
       17114 terminated  sed = |
       17115 terminated  sed -n 'p;n'
yes  0.86s user 0.06s system 5% cpu 16.994 total
sed =  9.06s user 0.30s system 55% cpu 16.993 total
sed -n 'p;n'  7.68s user 0.38s system 47% cpu 16.992 total
```

Above I tell it to increment on every 4000 lines. 17s later and I've processed 20
million lines. Of course the logic isn't serious there - we only read each line twice and count all of their characters, but the possibilities are pretty open. Also if you look closely you might notice it's seemingly the filters providing the input that are taking the majority of the time anyway.

Comment: it's worth noting that the shear complexity of the shell magic in this makes it not portable - it certainly doesnt run on bash4 on osx 10.9. :)     it wants to expand to use `dash`, and `sed -f -` doesnt make bsd sed happy either... not to mention having to pull the heredoc markers back to ^...

Answer (score 2):

GNU Parallel is made for this:

```
cat bigfile | parallel --pipe -N100 yourscript
```

It will default to running 1 job per CPU core. You can force running a single job with '-j1'.

Version 20140422 includes a fast version that can deliver 3.5 GB/s. The price is that it cannot deliver the exact 100 lines, but if you know the approximate line length you can set --block to 100 times that (here I assume the line length is close to 500 bytes):

```
parallel --pipepart --block 50k yourscript :::: bigfile
```