# redirect split output

Tags: bash, io-redirection, output, split

I split a gz file using `gunzip` piped to `split`:

```
time gunzip -c file.gz | split -l 500 -d -a 4 - pref_
```

Which generates the following files:

```
pref_0000 
pref_0001
```

I'd like to pipe those files to zip them again. I tried the following:

```
gunzip -c file.gz | split -l 500 -d -a 4 - pref_ | echo "file produced:" -
# Nothing

gunzip -c file.gz | split -l 500 -d -a 4 - pref_ | echo -
gunzip -c file.gz | split -l 500 -d -a 4 - pref_ | echo
```

Those do not work, how can I get an output from the split command? I expect to get the produced file names.

Comment: [How do I split to stdout for piping to a command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125649)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [--filter](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html) option of `split` to invoke `zip` on each split file

```
gunzip -c file.gz | split -l 500 -d -a 4 - pref_ --filter='zip $FILE'
```

Comment: I am sorry but my split does not have any option named filter. When I try it it says: `split: unrecognized option '--filter=gzip $FILE'` . Is it amatter of version? When I run `split --help` I cannot see any filtering option.

Comment: @user3298319, ah you're probably missing gnu split

Comment: it's strange because I have already installed gnu coreutils on my mac: `brew install coreutils`.

Comment: @user3298319, i have access to two versions of GNU `split`. V 8.24 supports `--filter`, V 5.97 does not. So I'm guessing it's about the version

Comment: @iruvar How can I find my version of `split`?  I have the same problem, and installed `split` with the same command.  But my error is, `split: illegal option -- -`  :D

Comment: @alex, are you on a Mac?

Comment: @iruvar Yes, I am.

Comment: @alex, could be one of two things, you're missing GNU split in which case `brew install coreutils` should do the trick as long as you make sure GNU split takes path precedence over the default split. Alternately you could have an older version of GNU split