# cat and split a file and upload to hdfs?

Tags: linux, perl, gzip, split

I am trying to achieve this scenario where I can split a gz file which is on local linux and upload to hdfs as part unzipped or zipped files without writing the split output to disk.
I am having issues after trying this below command.

below command writes to local disk then I can upload to hdfs which I don't want :-

```
zcat ./file.txt.gz | tail  -n +2 | split -l 20 - file.part 


hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ./*file.part* /folder/in/hdfs/
```

I want something like this is it achievable ?:-

```
zcat ./file.txt.gz | tail  -n +2 | split -l 20 | gzip -d | hdfs dfs -put - /folder/in/hdfs/file.part
```

Comment: You can't uncompressed only a part of a split gzip file.

Comment: See [How do I break up a file like split to stdout for piping to a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125649)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid split and do the splitting on your own:

```
number_of_files=5 # for you to determine
zcat ./file.txt.gz | for((i=0;i<5;i++)); do
    head -n 20 | hdfs dfs -put - /folder/in/hdfs/file.part_$i
done
```